# MySQL Multiple types of relationship among two tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 3 tables: [ 'users' , 'projects' , 'users_group' ] and two types of users ['students', 'supervisors']

Scenario:

all users information's is stored in the users table since they share the same properties, inside the users table there is a "user_type" column which is a foreign key referencing the id in the users_group table allowing me to differentiate the two types of users based on their user_type ID.

The projects table contains information about a project such as (project title, abstract, etc..).
My problem is: since a project can have one or multiples authors and vice-versa with and 1 supervisor but the supervisor can supervise one or multiple projects:

- How do i create a bridge table "projects_authors" between users (students users) and the projects table?
- at the same time how do i create a one-to-many like (project_supervisors) relationship between users table (supervisors users) and the projects table?

Comment: Can you please show us a capture of schema you have done already ?

Comment: update your question add the tables schema,  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .as text